# Need to convert multiple list of tuples into a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples as below

```
a=[[('key_1', '1'), ('key_1', '2'), ('key_1', '3')],
     [('key_2', '4'), ('key_2', '5'), ('key_2', '6')],
     [('key_3', '7'), ('key_3', '8'), ('key_3', '9')]]
```

I need to convert the above list to dictionary as below using python

```
{'key_2' : { '4' : {'key_1':'1','key_3':'7'}},
             '5' : {'key_1':'2','key_3':'8'}},
             '6' : {'key_1':'3','key_3':'9'}}}
```

My code is as below

```
d1={}
d2={}
d3={}
b=a.pop(1)
for i in b:
    d1[i[0]]=d2
    d1[i[0]][i[1]]=d3
    for j in a:
        for k in j:
            d1[i[0]][i[1]][k[0]]=k[1]

pprint.pprint(d1)
```

But I am getting,

```
{'key_2': {'4': {'key_1': '3', 'key_3': '9'},
           '5': {'key_1': '3', 'key_3': '9'},
           '6': {'key_1': '3', 'key_3': '9'}}}
```

instead of

```
{'key_2' : { '4' : {'key_1':'1','key_3':'7'}},
             '5' : {'key_1':'2','key_3':'8'}},
             '6' : {'key_1':'3','key_3':'9'}}}
```

How can get this dictionary?

Comment: Do you have some example code ? Because i don't think the way you're trying to build the list is valid.

Comment: The two data structures you've defined there are not syntactically valid. Could you please adjust?

Comment: This question has not become any more clear since the last time you asked it.

Comment: @sytech I now created three list. Need to put the values of three lists into the dictionary as above

Comment: @Alex the value of key "key_2" in your dict is invalid.

Comment: @Jclarke I have added my code.

Comment: You say "into a single dictionary" but your example shows nested dictionaries. Can you update the subject line?

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {}
map(lambda x:map(lambda (y,z):d.setdefault(y,[]).append(z),x),a)


d1 = {}
for n,i in enumerate(d['key_2']):
    b = []
    for j in a:
        if j[n][0] != 'key_2':
            b.append(j[n])
    d1.update({i:dict(b)})

print {'key_2':d1}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the code is not working. What do you denote by "c[n]" ? I don't have any variable set as "c"

Comment: This code is not working either. Can you please paste the output  also printed using this code?